# MySQL FK syntax: insert column called practice into table cred_insurances that is FK to table practices

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

I need to insert a column called "practice" into table "cred_insurances" that is a FK referencing table "practices" PK "id"

Comment: If you need to show us more information, eg. the output from commands, then please add it to the original post rather than add it as comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure that your MySQL table is using the InnoDB engine, by running the following from the mysql prompt.

```
show create table cred_insurances
```

the output will include (towards the bottom) the text `ENGINE=...`. If it is not InnodDB, then you will first need to convert it using the following SQL. You may need to do this to the parent table as well.

```
ALTER TABLE cred_insurances ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Then you can add a column and a foreign key constraint with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE cred_insurances
    ADD practice INT,
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_practice
    FOREIGN KEY (practice) REFERENCES practices (ID)
```

---

If you are having difficulties with errors whilst adding a foreign key, try the following command to get more detailed information on the error.

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

Comment: @ar: I altered both tables to InnoDB ok, but I keep getting "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table './credentialing1/#sql-8e1_58.frm' (errno: 150)" when I run the command. Advice?

Comment: @ar: I was able to execute your command after changing back to MyISAM, but how to verify it took?

Comment: @ar: I was able to do what I need without any ISAM to InnoDB change. Why did you feel it necessary to add that complexity? There must be some compelling reason, no?

Comment: @Captain Claptrap, MyISAM doesn't currently support foreign key constraints. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @ar: I'm confused now. Your link (and another I found) seem to prove what your saying, yet I think it is working. Here is the output of mysql> show create table cred_insurances;

Comment: | Table           | Create Table    
| cred_insurances | CREATE TABLE `cred_insurances` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ProviderName` tinytext,
  `Website(s)` text,
  `Notes` text,
  `practice` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_practice` (`practice`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=277 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Doesn't the line "KEY `fk_practice` (`practice`)" indicate the FK as desired? My application is working as if this is indeed a foreign key. Maybe I am misunderstanding FK's and constraints?

Comment: No, that line just tells you that there is a non-unique index (called fk_practice) on the practice column.

Comment: Obviously I have a lot to learn. When I made a new db and ran as you originally instructed I was able to do it as well as show the constraint in a show command (seeing it like that is very important to me). It showed ---CONSTRAINT `fk_practice` FOREIGN KEY (`practice`) REFERENCES `practices` (`ID`)--- which gives me peace of mind that it is now done right. I'm not sure why my first attempt failed with the 1005 error. Anyway, Thank you.